# How to force choice of installed App store?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have Google Play, Amazon, Samsung, etc stores on a phone. I want to give the user the choice of which market to go to. If I use market, it is going to the Google Play app by default. I want a list of them to appear. Do I have to manually check which are installed and have a custom choice screen? Or can I adjust my current code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appName)));
```

Comment: Well, you could test your approach really quick, right? What happens when you use the startActivity with the intent you are creating? Does it work as expected?

Comment: FYI - On my Samsung S4 it goes straight to the Google Play App Store

Comment: I see. Good question. I believe that you will have to search the list of apps installed and pick and present the available markets as a custom list. I am afraid you can't use Uri market protocol for this since market is strictly tied to Google Play and not any other market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example:

```
// get app which can open fill
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAppOpeners(Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<Map<String, Object>> appinfos = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    ResolveInfo app = null;
    List<ResolveInfo> mApps = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();

    PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
    mApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT);// get app which can open fill
    Iterator<ResolveInfo> it = mApps.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        app = it.next();
        if (true) {// mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.activityInfo.packageName)
                    // != null
            item.put("packname", app.activityInfo.packageName);// packname of app
            item.put("appname", app.loadLabel(mContext.getPackageManager()));// name of app
            item.put("icon", app.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager()));// icon of app
            item.put("intent", intent);
            appinfos.add(item);
        }
    }
    //appinfos = StringSortUtil.sortString(appinfos, "appname");
    return appinfos;
}
```

The codes is used for screening apps which can open file by mimetype,.It is maybe usefull for you

I am sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you missing code? I add the imports suggested in Eclipse but I am still left with so many missing declarations and stuff that confuses me. Can you post all declarations and other relevant code as this is confusing me. Is KEY_ICON a drawable we add or is it extracted automatically, because it is not recognised.......etc

Comment: I am sorry ,I modify my codes again , This method is used for screening apps

Comment: My email address is bjltxsp@gmail.com,You could send message for me if you do not see,I have bad English,So sorry!

Comment: This is beyond my level of understanding so I may just give you the tick and outsource the work as a self-contained separate popup activity. Thanks for your answer.